# MUI Pagination Dynamic count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using mui react for my project.

In the Pagination component, I am supposed to provide the count to show the total number of pages.

In this instance, I have 27 total products, and I'm supposed to have 2 pages since each page contains 20 products. This is what i get.

[image]

How do i make it integers.

```
<Pagination
                count={
                  productsCount % 20 === 0
                    ? productsCount / 20
                    : productsCount / 20 + 1
                }
                page={page}
                onChange={handlePageChange}
                color='primary'
                variant='outlined'
              />
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is this to have round up numbers for the pagination. Let me know if it helps.

```
<Pagination
                count={Math.ceil(productsCount / 20)}
                page={page}
                onChange={handlePageChange}
                color='primary'
                variant='outlined'
              />
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/paginationoutlined-demo-material-ui-forked-xo3i53?file=/demo.js) with a working example including an example with a higher number of products.